# How to know if the mouse is down on clicking a column divider in a Datagridview Control

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, mouseevent

I am trying to show a message to the user that will tell them

> "don't resize column"

as soon as they try to drag the column divider in a `DataGridView`.

Is there any event like a `DataGridViewColumnDividerMouseDrag` in vb.net?

I would like to know how my mouse pointer is behaving when the column divider of a `DataGridView` is clicked

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why don't you just disable resizing?

Comment: not always i want to stop user to resize the column but in case of selected row, i want to stop them as per requirement.

Comment: @picnic4u - you want to stop user from resizing a column for selected row...right? Column resizing is done for the entire column. Even if you provide a message for selected row, user can go and resize the column from divider in row above/below selected row.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a global variable that captures the `MouseDown` on `DataGridView` then use a `DataGridView.ColumnWidthChanged` event to capture a change in column width.

You would need to add some code to make the `DataGridView` save the width before the change and revert it back to that width. This code will allow you to mix `MouseDown` and `DataGridView.ColumnWidthChanged`

Not really a `columndividermouseDrag` event but its a start

***Global variables***

```
Dim mousestatus As Boolean
Dim global_e As MouseEventArgs
```

***Capture Events***

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.MouseDown
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        mousestatus = True
        global_e = e
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView2_Mouseup(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.MouseUp
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        mousestatus = False
        global_e = e
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub DataGridView2_ColumnWidthChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
                DataGridViewColumnEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.ColumnWidthChanged

    If mousestatus = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("don't resize column")
    Else
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: in case of selected row, user can't resize the column width either with columndivider mouse drag option or column divider mouse double click option. so in both case, i want to show message to user that you can not resize the column.

in this situation columnwidthchanged event will not be fired as column width will not change.

here after double click also ColumnDividerDoubleClick event is not firing as during mouse double click mouse pointer's columnIndex is coming as columnheader click like 1, 2,3...

please let me know if not clear.